# How can I log data from HttpRequest and HttpResponse at the same time?

Tags: java, logging, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have some custom logging logic that logs information from the request and response. Some log lines contain information **from both the request and the response at the same time**. Thus, I somehow need to be able to access both at the same time to create the necessary log lines.

When using Feign this was easy to do since you can just set a logger on the builder, and the fact that the response object has the request object in it makes it easy to retrieve data from both.

However, with apache HttpClient, such access does not exist.

I could only find `addInterceptorFirst` and `addInterceptorFirst` for each of request and response, but never both.

The only place I was able to access both objects is at the `send()` method like so:

```
@Override
public HttpResponse send(String method, String path, Map<String, String> headers, HttpEntity httpEntity) throws IOException {
    HttpUriRequest request = getHttpUriRequest(method, path, headers, httpEntity);
    try (CloseableHttpClient httpClient = httpClientBuilder.build()) {
        HttpResponse httpResponse =  httpClient.execute(request);
        httpClientLogger.logRequestResponse(request, httpResponse); // logging here
        return httpResponse;
    }
}
```

This works fine except for one problem.

There are interceptors that are adding headers to the request internally (inside the `httpClient.execute(request)` method) and they seem to be creating a deep copy of the request object since after the request is done, the object in the code snippet is not modified to include the added headers.

Question: How can I log info from the request and the response at the same time, while having the request contain all relevant information that may be added through interceptors?

Comment: You should add the `apache-httpclient-..` tag (4.x or 5.x) so the right people can see your question

Comment: @Jorn done, thank you :)

Comment: Have you considered a different approach by using a custom request and response logging interceptor?

Comment: @M.Pour I have info log lines that contain data from both the request and the response, so I can't seperate them. And I can't change what the logs are supposed to look like

Comment: You can try creating a request interceptor that stores the request in the `HttpContext`, then create a response interceptor that reads it from the `HttpContext`, then logs both the request and response.

Comment: @RobSpoor thanks for the idea, I'm currently exploring using `ThreadLocal` to acheive the same goal. From what I can tell `HttpContext` isn't always thread-safe (based on the stored attribute) so I might prefer to stick to `ThreadLocal` if it works since I don't have that headache. Do let me know though if there's a specific reason you recommend using `HttpContext`!

Comment: @MissSkooter because if you don't manually pass an `HttpContext` when sending the request, you get one for your request only. That means that the request and response get the same instance, and no other request or response will get that same instance.

Comment: @RobSpoor yeah I see your point, it's definitely better but now my problem is that I can't compute the duration of the request through the interceptors. (I am using `System.nanoTime()` before and after execute)

Comment: @MissSkooter sure you can. Store the start date in the context in the request interceptor, read it in the response interceptor. I do that all the time.

Comment: Here's an example of a project I'm working on for my employer: https://github.com/Ingenico-ePayments/connect-sdk-java/blob/56edd93d4860ff4d6f4375213b7d52f3218894e5/src/main/java/com/ingenico/connect/gateway/sdk/java/defaultimpl/DefaultConnection.java#L369. It creates its own `HttpContext` for each request so it's already available for the start time before the request interceptor is called.

Comment: @RobSpoor thank you for all the help! Feel free to write up an answer and I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a request interceptor that stores the request in the `HttpContext`, then create a response interceptor that reads it from the `HttpContext`, then logs both the request and response.

If you provide a `HttpContext` (implementing class: `BasicHttpContext`) yourself when executing the request, you can populate it with some extra fields like the start date. Otherwise, the HTTP client will create one for each request separately.